# Powershell process from java - Process may "delay" (Not hang) on some environments

Tags: java, powershell

We are creating a bunch of PoSH scripts and running them in an orderly manner from Java
(Building a process, handling all input/output streams that may cause hangups, and then invoke it using local admin privileges).

We are facing an interesting occurrence in some of our deployments.
When tracking the log file of this operation we sometime see a considerable delay. The
delay is **consistent** and clocks at 35 seconds:
If there's a log listing just prior to the process building and the next logging is done
from the invoked PoSH script - **The delay between them is consistent and of 35 seconds.
It is consistent for all scripts invoked on that machine.**

This behavior is not consistent. We have several (unrelated) machines that exhibit that behavior, but also many other that show 2-5 seconds which we accept as a normal time for building the process.

Our Java process is a 32bit process, and most of the delaying machines are 64bit VMs of Win2K8 server R2. Most of these VMs are using domain authentication and policies (Different ones of different customers).

We tried running the Powershell via various different methods (Such as PSTools) but with no real findings - It always starts in a few seconds. Comparing machine installations did not bring us any insights either. Performance does not seem to be an issue either though I'll admit we haven't analyzed it too deeply, just looked closely at the task manager.

It is important to mention that the process never hangs - It will run and run swiftly when started. The delay is happening during the startup of the PoSH process.

Any ideas, advices or speculative directions will be more than welcome.

Thanks,
Yaron